# How to make a Jquery AJAX post to fill a table without ending up on the wrong url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I need to fill a table of a given page of my Django site, say its url is `/`.
I have an ajax code to pull the table contents from another url: `/suggest/`

this is the AJAX code:

```
var frm = $('#sugg');
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#suggestion").append(data);
                window.location="";
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $("#MESSAGE-DIV").html("Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

it fetches the table html correctly but renders it on a blank page on the `/suggest/` url, instead of just filling the div `$('#suggestion')`, and remaining on the `/` url.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are moving your page with the 
`window.location="";`

Remove this line and try again

Comment: Tried that. didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This was just that the javascript code was not catching the submit event. Had to move the code into the Window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
    //mycode
};
```